# Converter o caminho de um arquivo para String

Tags: java, json, arquivo

Estou precisando de ajuda, preciso ler um arquivo JSON (estou usando a biblioteca GSON), e para isso preciso transformar uma variável do tipo Path para uma String.
Segue abaixo o código para melhor compreensão.

```
public void gravaJson(String nomeArq) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = gson.toJson(lista);

    try {
        final Writer writer = new FileWriter(nomeArq);
        gson.toJson(json, writer);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readJson(String nomeArq) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Path caminho = Paths.get(nomeArq);
    String path; //Preciso converter o caminho para String
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Object json = gson.fromJson(bufferedReader, Object.class);

    System.out.println(json.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
path = Paths.get(nomeArq).toAbsolutePath().toString();
```